# Prove that $X=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is Not complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that $X=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with the metric $d(f,g)=\int^1_0|f(x)-g(x)|dx$ is not a complete metric space.

**My idea**

Consider the sequence of continuous functions
$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &  0\le x \le \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}& \\ 
 nx+(1-\frac{1}{n})& \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n} \le x \le \frac{1}{2}& \\ 
 1& \frac{1}{2} \le x \le 1 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

We have $d(f_n,f_m)=\int ^1_0 |f_n-f_m|dx=\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$, and hence $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Now, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Do you know what else you would have to prove about $f_n$ in order to show that the space is not complete?

Comment: $f_n$ is convergent to a function which is not continuous

Comment: Yes, or at least '$f_n$ does not converge to a continuous function' (so if you show that it does converge to a discontinuous function you're done).

Comment: But... I don't think that $f_n$ as you defined it is a continuous function for each $n$ (let alone the fact that the definition might be a little ambiguous for $n=1$, but that's not a big deal; the continuity of $f_n$ is).

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum [If you show that it does converge to a discontinuous function] ---> converge not pointwise but for $d(.,.)$ otherwise $x^n$ tends to zero in this space.

Comment: That's it. I was going to say that and got distracted wondering wether $f_n$ so defined was right. Good that you mentioned it.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum It cannot converge to a discontinuous function because these are not in the domain of the metric. So maybe extend the domain to all Riemann or Lebesgue integrable functions on $[0,1]$, and show that space is Hausdorff?

Comment: I edited $f_n$ now

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, I've actually just made that suggestion at PtF 's answer in order to make it right. I think that is the easiest path, isn't it?

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum it isn’t as easy as that as $d$ is not a metric on Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: That's true... and I don't see that considering $\mathcal L^1/\sim$ with $\sim$ being _equality a.e._ turns out to be very useful... because, how do you go back?

Comment: On the other hand, I don't think we can assume much topological background for this question.

Comment: The set $X$ is often denoted by $C[0,1]$  for brevity of notation.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum. The def;n of $f_n$ has been edited by the proposer but it is contradictory.  For $n\geq  2$ the first line of the def'n of  $f_n$ implies $ f_n(1/2-1/n)=0$ but the second line implies $f_n(1/2-1/n)=n(1/2-1/n)+(1-1/n)=n/2-1/n\ne 0$..... If we amend the first line to read "... $0\leq x<1/2-1/n$ " then $f_n (1/2-1/n)$ is defined but $f_n(x)$ will be discontinuous at $x=1/2-1/n$ for each  $ n\geq 3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence $f_n$ does not work since those are not continuous functions. If you don't know how to fix it, a good option is to define
$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
nx &  0\le x \le \frac{1}{n}\\ 
1 & \frac 1n <x\le 1.\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now, instead of proving that it converges point-wise to a discontinuous function (which says nothing) you have to prove that there is no $f\in C\big([0,1]\big)$ such that $d(f_n,f)\to 0$ (for the distance of the metric space).

One option is to suppose, on the contrary, that there is a continuous $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that 
$$\int_0^1 \big|f_n(x)-f(x)\big|\,dx \to 0.$$
Suppose that $f(0)=y_0$ and take $\delta>0$ (and maybe $\delta<1$) such that
$$0\le x<\delta\implies |f(x)-y_0|<\tfrac12,$$
(that is, 'take $\varepsilon=\tfrac12$') which is possible since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Now show that there is an $N$ such that for $n\ge N$
$$\int_0^1 |f_n(x)-f(x)| \, dx$$
is greater than a certain positive lower bound (I guess you can try to integrate in $[0,\delta]$ and take $N$ such that $\tfrac1N<\delta$, so $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n(\delta)=1$ for $n\ge N$).

Then is not true that $f_n \to f$ in the space, which is absurd.

Comment: I assume that "converges punctually" means "converges point-wise".

Comment: Yes, thanks, btw.

Comment: I thought that $f_n$ converges to a continuous function, which is $1$.
Because $\int_0^1 |f_n(x) - 1| dx = \int_0^{1/n} (1 - nx) dx = 1/2n$.